# Migrating HSQL to Mysql but 404 Error on site

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have problem on migrating hsql to mysql. First i already run it on ant tomcat with hsql then i want to use it with mysql. I followed all steps on this documentaion http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/c ... l-tutorial

But it has error when accessing the site it give error 404. and when i checked on database. all tables are created but their is no data on some of it.

here the some log.

[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 15:34:02 SchemaExport - HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
[artifact:mvn] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ImportScriptException: Error during statement execution (file: '/sql/load_i18n_countries.sql'): INSERT INTO BLC_ISO_COUNTRY (ALPHA_2, NAME, ALPHA_3, NUMERIC_CODE, STATUS) VALUES ('AX', 'Åland Islands', 'ALA', '248', 'OFFICIALLY_ASSIGNED')
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.importScript(SchemaExport.java:451)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:378)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:498)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
[artifact:mvn] at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
[artifact:mvn] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:51)

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: same problem but no answer http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?t=4539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to MySQL not running in UTF-8 mode. See this link in the Broadleaf docs: http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/database-configuration/mysql.

Basically, ensure that your my.cnf configuration tells MySQL to run with the following:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

You will need to restart MySQL for this to take effect. After you do this, you might need to create another schema that will be defaulted to UTF-8. If you don't configure this, MySQL usually starts up in MYISAM which is incompatible with UTF-8. I'm not sure if you can change an existing schema from MYISAM to UTF-8; probably easier if you just create a new schema.